# disable the constraints in plsql without given any name

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

here is my code

```
Create table Issue(
Lib_Issue_Id Number(10) Primary Key,
Book_No number(6),
Member_Id number(5),
Issue_Date Date,
Return_Date Date,
check (Issue_date<Return_Date),
FOREIGN KEY (Book_No) REFERENCES Books(Book_No),
FOREIGN KEY (Member_Id) REFERENCES Member(Member_Id)
);
```

now after creating table. I want to disable all the constraints but I am not given it to any name, then how can I disable the constraints..???

Comment: (You may want to re-word `I am not given it to any name` - *not given any constraint names to do so*?)

Comment: Do you insist on constraints created as shown, or would you accept manipulating constraints created *after* table creation?

Comment: I don't see that it makes any difference whether you personally named the constraints  or not. They all have names in the data dictionary, and you just drive a loop off `user/all/dba_constraints`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer is "put names on the constraints, and later generations of programmers will sing paeans to your name forever". However, if eternal gratitude from your colleagues isn't something you're into [the docs for the ALL_CONSTRAINTS view can be found here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022). Use a cursor to read the constraint names from the view, then disable them, as in:

```
FOR aRow IN (SELECT *
               FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ISSUE' AND
                     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R')
LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || 
                     aRow.TABLE_NAME ||
                    ' MODIFY CONSTRAINT ' ||
                    aRow.CONSTRAINT_NAME ||
                    ' DISABLE';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FK constraint ' || aRow.CONSTRAINT_NAME || ' disabled');
END LOOP;
```